# Python: Send a POST request using just a raw string

Tags: python, post, custom-action

I want to send a POST request using just a raw string.

I'm writing a parser. I've loaded page and seen such a complicated request with many headers and body in firebug:

```
__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEW.... (11Kb or unreadable text)
```

How can I send this exact request one more time (headers+post body) manually (passing it as a huge string)?

Like:

```
func("%(headers) \n \n %(body)" % ... )
```

I want it to be send by my script (and response to be handled) and don't want to make a dictionary of parameters and headers manually.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know what the headers are and what the body is?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid , I've copied it from firebug. I'm going to parse the response .

Comment: I dont understand the details of the process you are trying to achieve. Are you asking how to send a POST request using just a raw string from python? It starts to throw me when you are talking about firebug as if there is something clientside you want to do

Comment: @jdi, yes, just a request using a raw string from python. thank you for wording this.

Comment: You may have no choice but to at least convert the headers to a dict so that you can add it to the request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answer just got too big and confusing and was showing more than what you are asking. I felt I should include a more concise answer for future readers to come across:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import urlparse

# this was the header and data strings you already had
headers = 'baz=3&foo=1&bar=2'
data = 'baz=3&foo=1&bar=2'

header_dict = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(headers))

r = urllib2.Request('http://www.foo.com', data, headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(r)
```

You will need to at least parse the headers back into a dict, but its minimal work. Then just pass it all along to a new request.

*Note: This concise example assumes both your headers and your data body are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. If the headers are in a raw string format like `Key: Value`, then see the other answer for more detail on parsing that first.

Ultimately, you can't just copy-paste the raw text and run a new request. It has to be divided into header and data in the proper formats.

Comment: `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request` with [this](http://pastebin.com/JtyGfcEa) crazy request generated by [this](http://www.sberbank-ast.ru/purchaseList.aspx) page when querying "Название аукциона" = Ford . Have you got any ideas why it could be?

Comment: Did you actually separate your headers and your body already, and are they both `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: My post-body was wrong. Now it works. But sometimes server answers with wrong encoding (I can see only trash in my output), despite the fact header is `'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3' `. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

# DATA:

# option #1 - using a dictionary
values = {'name': 'Michael Foord', 'location': 'Northampton', 'language': 'Python' }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)

# option #2 - directly as a string
data = 'name=Michael+Foord&language=Python&location=Northampton'

# HEADERS:

# option #1 - convert a bulk of headers to a dictionary (really, don't do this)    

headers = '''
Host: www.http.header.free.fr
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg,
Accept-Language: Fr
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 4.0)
Connection: Keep-Alive
'''

headers = dict([[field.strip() for field in pair.split(':', 1)] for pair in headers.strip().split('\n')])

# option #2 - just use a dictionary

headers = {'Accept': 'image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg,',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Accept-Language': 'Fr',
           'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
           'Host': 'www.http.header.free.fr',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 4.0)'}

# send the request and receive the response

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi', data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: It seems that it works somehow even without headers. But I'd better convert them into dictionary. Thank you, @jdi .

Comment: @MInner: `urlparse.parse_qsl(headers)`

Comment: Your example of the headers is assuming the OP already has the dictionary. Maybe start with my `urlparse` suggestion and just pass that to the header value, instead of all that big header parsing stuff

Comment: Added headers to the post. You should simply pass the headers as a dictionary. The alternative is to convert them to a dictionary, or to use sockets and implement part of the HTTP protocol yourself. I don't believe this is what you want.